# How to drop files onto a COleDropTarget from an external process in C#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, com

I'm trying to have an outside process drop files programmatically onto a COleDropTarget using C# code. I can actually get a pointer to the target this way:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetProp(IntPtr hWnd, string lpString);

IntPtr targetPtr = GetProp(hWnd, "OleDropTargetInterface");
```

I know I get a valid pointer, I've been able to validate it. I'm stuck with what to do next, most of what I think should work produces a 0xc0000005 (access violation) error. Here are a few things I tried:

```
Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr);
Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(targetPtr, typeof(IDropTarget));
EnterpriseServicesHelper.WrapIUnknownWithComObject(targetPtr);
```

I understand that I probably can't get a pointer to that memory space since my process doesn't doesn't own it. If that's the case, how does explorer do it?

As for the IDropTarget above, the interface is defined as such in my application:

```
[ComImport, InterfaceType((short)1), Guid("00000122-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface IDropTarget
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void DragEnter([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDataObject pDataObj, [In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] uint grfKeyState, [In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.POINTL")] POINTL pt, [In, Out, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] ref uint pdwEffect);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void DragOver([In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] uint grfKeyState, [In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.POINTL")] POINTL pt, [In, Out, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] ref uint pdwEffect);
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void DragLeave();
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
    void Drop([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IDataObject pDataObj, [In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] uint grfKeyState, [In, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.POINTL")] POINTL pt, [In, Out, ComAliasName("Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.DWORD")] ref uint pdwEffect);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Explorer doesn't do it, the system (Ole32/Com/Rpc) does it. It's the only one who knows how to marshal the IDropTarget from the target process to the source process. It knows how because the target called RegisterDropDrop (which indeed created this undocumented "OleDropTargetInterface" property an another "OleEndPointID" one)

Comment: Thanks Simon, it sure sounds like I am out of options given what you have said. Is there an avenue of research that you might suggest next?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any suggestion :-)